# Buttons that run a specific sequence of events (verbose code that I don't know how to simplify)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working, but it's incredibly verbose and I know that it can be made more compact. I just don't know how :-)

I'm building an audio portfolio. When a button is clicked, a sequence of events happens. When another button is clicked, all other active buttons are killed and the sequence for that specific button runs.

The buttons are invisible and are placed on a visualisation of a switch. When clicked, an image of the switch flicked into its "activated" state has its class of "display: none" removed. That should give the user the impression that actually flicking a switch starts playing audio.

Like so:

```
$(function(){

  // FIRST BUTTON
  $('.button01').click(function() {
    if ($('.switch01').hasClass('activated')){

    // So if button.button01 is clicked and img.switch01 has class "activated"

      // Kill all audio
      $('audio').each(function(){ this.pause(); this.currentTime = 0; });

      // Turn this switch off
      $('.switch01').removeClass('activated');

      // Kill all info cards showing the playback controls
      $('.audio-info-card').addClass('d-none');
    } else { 


    // If button.button01 is clicked and img.switch01 DOESN'T have class "activated"

      // Turn all other switches off
      $('.switch02, .switch03').removeClass('activated');

      // Kill all info cards
      $('.audio-info-card').addClass('d-none');

      // Activate this switch and info card
      $('.switch01').addClass('activated');
      $('.audio-info-card#card01').removeClass('d-none');

      // Kill all audio
      $('audio').each(function(){ this.pause(); this.currentTime = 0; });

      // Start this audio
      $('#audio01-player')[0].play();
    }
  });

  // SECOND BUTTON
  $('.button02').click(function() {
    if ($('.switch02').hasClass('activated')){ 

    // So if button.button02 is clicked and img.switch02 has class "activated"

      // Kill all audio
      $('audio').each(function(){ this.pause(); this.currentTime = 0; });

      // Turn this switch off
      $('.switch02').removeClass('activated');

      // Kill all info card showing the playback controls
      $('.audio-info-card').addClass('d-none');
    } else { 


    // If button.button02 is clicked and img.switch02 DOESN'T have class "activated"

      // Turn all other switches off
      $('.switch01, .switch03').removeClass('activated');

      // Kill all info cards
      $('.audio-info-card').addClass('d-none');

      // Activate this switch and info card
      $('.switch02').addClass('activated');
      $('.audio-info-card#card02').removeClass('d-none');

      // Kill all audio
      $('audio').each(function(){ this.pause(); this.currentTime = 0; });

      // Start this audio
      $('#audio02-player')[0].play();
    }
  });
```

There are 16 buttons. I realize this code is stupid but JS / jQuery isn't my strong suit :-D

Fortunately, the code works, but any help making this simpler would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try posting this on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: Are there just 3 elements with the classes switch01, switch02 and switch03 or are there also 16 of them?

Comment: @matthias_h there are currently 16 instances of everything, so everything ending in 01, 02 et cetera also has a 03, 04, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the `click()` event for all buttons with a class name starting with `button` like this:

```
  $('button[class^="button"]').click(function() {
     let buttonNr = $(this).attr("class").substr(6);
     if ($('.switch' + buttonNr).hasClass('activated')) {
        $('audio').each(function() {
           this.pause();
           this.currentTime = 0;
        });

        $('.switch' + buttonNr).removeClass('activated');
        $('.audio-info-card').addClass('d-none');
     } else {

        $('[class^="switch"]').removeClass('activated');
        $('.audio-info-card').addClass('d-none');
        $('.switch' + buttonNr).addClass('activated');
        $('.audio-info-card#card' + buttonNr).removeClass('d-none');

        $('audio').each(function() {
           this.pause();
           this.currentTime = 0;
        });

        $('#audio' + buttonNr + '-player')[0].play();
     }
 });
```